# Show 'add comment' link for status updates in Twenty Thirteen

Tags: comments, post-status, theme-twenty-thirteen

I have WP 3.6 running on my server. After playing around with it, I noticed that it's not very intuitive to add comments to a status update;

[image]
<sup>Guess how?</sup>

After some thought, I have decided I would like for it to look more like this:

[image]

<sup>Or some variation thereof</sup>

The `click to show/leave comments` text is simply appended on the end of the existing `Status on...` link.

I've dug around in the PHP files, but can't seem to figure out how to make this simple change. Is there a file somewhere that dictates what strings to display?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the `/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/functions.php` file and change the line

```
$format_prefix = ( has_post_format( 'chat' ) || has_post_format( 'status' ) ) ? _x( '%1$s on %2$s', '1: post format name. 2: date', 'twentythirteen' ): '%2$s';
```

to

```
$format_prefix = ( has_post_format( 'chat' ) || has_post_format( 'status' ) ) ? _x( '%1$s on %2$s - show/leave comments', '1: post format name. 2: date', 'twentythirteen' ): '%2$s';
```